# Validating the presence only if other simple_form field equals certain input?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, simple-form

In my simple_form a user can select a `discount_type`. With JQuery, the `apply_on` field is hidden when the DOM is loaded and only shows when the `discount_type` *percent* is selected.

**Issue:**
I only want to validate the presence for `apply_on` when `discount_type` `percent` is selected, but I don't know how/where to do this?

**form**

```
<div class="col col-sm-4"><%= f.input :discount_type, collection: ['percent', 'price'] %></div>
<div class="col col-sm-4 apply_on_percentage"><%= f.input :apply_on, collection: ['reservation total', 'accommodation total'], prompt: "Choose on what to apply the discount" %></div>

<script>
  // Hide form field when DOM is loaded
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.apply_on_percentage').hide();
  });

  // Load form field when percentage is selected
  $(document).on("change", "#discount_discount_type", function(){
    var discount_type = $(this).val();
    if(discount_type === 'percent'){
      $('.apply_on_percentage').show();
    } else{
      $('.apply_on_percentage').hide();
    }
  });


</script>
```

Comment: Are you asking about the server side validation? In that case you can just use the `if:` option with a lambda. `validates_presence_of :apply_on, if: ->{ discount_type == 'percent' }`. I would use a ActiveRecord::Enum for the discount types though.

Comment: Hi Max, thanks a lot for this. It worked. Good comment on enum, think this indeed will make things more efficient/scalable.

Comment: Feel free to use it if you want to answer the question yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per Max' answer, I can add the following to the discount model:

```
validates_presence_of :apply_on, if: ->{ discount_type == 'percent' }
```